# Отказывается работать загрузка файлов когда выполняется подгрузка формы через метод load

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть форма которая подгружается с помощью метода load и в эту форму пытаюсь подключить загрузку файлов jQuery File Upload. Если форма загружается сразу без метода load то загрузка файлов работает отлично. Но когда выполняется подгрузка формы через метод load то загрузка файлов работать отказывается не могу понять почему.

```
$('.katCatalog').live('change', function() {
    var id = $(this).val();
    var ident = $('.catalogs').val();
    $(".formAdds").load("/ks_tpl/modules/formsAdd.php",
        { id : id, ident : ident },
        function() {
            formSendsKat();
    });
});

function formSendsKat() { 
  jQuery(".submitsFormsValid").live('click', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var m_data= jQuery('.addKatalogsData').serialize();
    jQuery.ajax({ 
      type: 'POST', 
      url: '/ajax/addkatalogs.php', 
      data: m_data,
      success: function(result) { 
        if(result.result == true) { 
          //alert(); 
        } else { } //$('#upload_form').slideUp(1000);
        jQuery('.resultFormAjax').html(result); 
      } 
    }); 
  }); 
}
```

Ничего необычного а в файле только стандартный код для подключения плагина.

Если необходимо вот ссылка на официальную страницу загрузчика http://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/

Comment: Покажите ваш код

Comment: Не знаю как показать код стандартная подгрузка $('.katCatalog').live('change', function(){
  
  var id = $(this).val();
  var ident = $('.catalogs').val();
  
  $(".formAdds").load(
    "/ks_tpl/modules/formsAdd.php",
    {
   id : id,
   ident : ident
    },function(){
   
   
   
     
     formSendsKat(); });
  
 });

В подгружаемом файле подключены все файлы скрипта для загрузки.

Comment: Неплохо было бы увидеть так же код formSendsKat() и место, где происходит инициализация jQuery File Upload.

Comment: function formSendsKat()
 {
   
  
  jQuery(".submitsFormsValid").live('click', function(e){
   
   e.preventDefault();
   
   var m_data= jQuery('.addKatalogsData').serialize();
    
    
    jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/ajax/addkatalogs.php',
    data: m_data,
    success: function(result){
     
     if(result.result == true)
     {
      //alert();
     }
     else
     {
      
     } 
     //$('#upload_form').slideUp(1000);
     jQuery('.resultFormAjax').html(result);
    }
    });
   
  });
  
 
 }

Ничего необычного а в файле только стандартный код для подключения плагина

Comment: После подгрузки скрипта методом load и попытки добавить файл на загрузку выходит следующие http://joxi.ru/Dr8o3Bdfk9ddRA

Comment: Я правильно понял, что код инициализации плагина находится в formsAdd.php?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39117/discussion-between-alexsis20102-and-sergey-gornostaev).